# Is it possible to get GNOME Shell 'Activities' Overview to show windows from all Workspaces?

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, window, activities-overview

By default, the 'Activities' Overview in GNOME Shell only shows windows from the current workspace.

Is there some  way to get it show the **all** open windows instead?

I'm looking for functionality like that of the Compiz Scale's Spread feature, when used for windows from all workspaces.

Comment: How did you install Gnome Shell on your Ubuntu? Which repo?

Comment: I used ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible with this [Overview all windows extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/873/overview-all-windows/).

Although it won't work after install, download the schemas folder from its [git repo](https://github.com/amiller27/OverviewAllWindows) and paste in extension folder.

Path of extension folder:
`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/OverviewAllWindows@amiller27`

Overview shortcut will be <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! for changing hotkey read https://github.com/amiller27/OverviewAllWindows/issues/16#issuecomment-489218727