# Is it possible to show all open windows using shortcuts on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, window

When I was using Ubuntu 16.04, I could use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to show *all* open windows (not just the ones from the current workspace). But after I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, it seems I cannot do the same thing.

I have forced <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to [switch only on current workspace in GNOME shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464946/force-alt-tab-to-switch-only-on-current-workspace-in-gnome-shell/464947#464947).

Comment: I don't think it's related to forcing Alt+Tab to switch only on current workspace.

Comment: But the case is the `windows` in other workspaces just won't show up, but at odd times I need to check whether a window is open and I don't want to check each workspace one by one.

Comment: That's what I meant, it *does not depend* on whether you have forced Alt+Tab to switch only on current workspace. Even if you disable it, <Super> will show windows only from the current workspace.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I just checked that `SUPER` along will not make a difference just showing the windows in the current workspace. But is there really no way I can achieve what I mentioned? Some tweaks or tricks?

Comment: Yes, there is a GNOME extension which does the job: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/873/overview-all-windows/, but most probably installing from the website won't work. You need to follow the answer thoroughly: https://askubuntu.com/a/972346/480481

Comment: Great, @pomsky thank you so much. I will look into it.